# How to download PDF using URL in iOS app multiple times

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, nsfilemanager, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am getting getting multiple PDF urls from server response and showing them in tableview with download option for each cell.

I am able to download each pdf file only once, But, Tried to second time download, It is showing already downloaded error.

How to fix this?

Here is my code

```
 func downloadButtonTapped(index: Int) {
        
        let finalUrlStr = "(dataResponse?[index].brochure)")
        
        let fileURL = URL(string: finalUrlStr)
        let fileName = String((fileURL!.lastPathComponent)) as NSString
        
        // Create destination URL
        let documentsUrl:URL =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let destinationFileUrl = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent("\(fileName)")
        //Create URL to the source file you want to download
        let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig)
        let request = URLRequest(url:fileURL!)
        LoadingView.show()
        let task = session.downloadTask(with: request) { (tempLocalUrl, response, error) in
            if let tempLocalUrl = tempLocalUrl, error == nil {
                // Success
                if let statusCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode {
                    print("Successfully downloaded. Status code: \(statusCode)")
                }
                do {
                    try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: tempLocalUrl, to: destinationFileUrl)
                    do {
                        //Show UIActivityViewController to save the downloaded file
                        let contents  = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentsUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .skipsHiddenFiles)
                        for indexx in 0..<contents.count {
                            if contents[indexx].lastPathComponent == destinationFileUrl.lastPathComponent {
                                let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [contents[indexx]], applicationActivities: nil)
                                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 1) {
                                    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                                    LoadingView.hide()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (let err) {
//                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        print("error: \(err.localizedDescription)")
                        LoadingView.hide()
                        self.showBasicAlert(title: "\(err.localizedDescription)", message: "")
                       // }
                    }
                } catch (let writeError) {
                    print("Error creating a file \(destinationFileUrl) : \(writeError)")
                    LoadingView.hide()
                    self.showBasicAlert(title: "\(writeError.localizedDescription)", message: "")
                }
            } else {
                print("Error took place while downloading a file. Error description: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")")
                self.showBasicAlert(title: "\(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")", message: "")
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

[image]

Even though, PDF not downloaded even one time before download file, activitycontroller displaying and If we close that without download/save file, Again trying to download, Same error message showing like **already exist file**

How to download multiple times like whenever user taps on download option, It should download the pdf file.
Also after downloaded pdf, I need to show open pdf from external not inside app

> Any suggestions?

Comment: [`copyItem(at: to:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1412957-copyitem) *If a file with the same name already exists at dstUrl, this method stops the copy attempt and returns an appropriate error.* Either check to see if the file already exists and just open it instead of downloading it again or delete the existing file before dowinloading it again

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it by myself by removing condition.
Now I am able to download whenever user tap on download button.
Here is the code.

```
 func downloadButtonTapped(index: Int) {
        //     print("index \(index)")
        
        let finalUrlStr = "(dataResponse?[index].brochure)")
        let fileURL = URL(string: finalUrlStr)
        if let fileUrl = fileURL {
            let fileName = String((fileUrl.lastPathComponent)) as NSString
            
            // Create destination URL
            let documentsUrl:URL =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
            let destinationFileUrl = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent("\(fileName)")
            //Create URL to the source file you want to download
            let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
            let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig)
            let request = URLRequest(url:fileUrl)
            LoadingView.show()
            let task = session.downloadTask(with: request) { (tempLocalUrl, response, error) in
                if error == nil {
                    // Success
                    if let statusCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode {
                        print("Successfully downloaded. Status code: \(statusCode)")
                    }
                    do {
                        //Show UIActivityViewController to save the downloaded file
                        let contents  = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentsUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .skipsHiddenFiles)
                        for indexx in 0..<contents.count {
                            if contents[indexx].lastPathComponent == destinationFileUrl.lastPathComponent {
                                let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [contents[indexx]], applicationActivities: nil)
                                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 1) {
                                    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                                    LoadingView.hide()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (let err) {
                        print("error: \(err.localizedDescription)")
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            LoadingView.hide()
                            self.showBasicAlert(title: "\(err.localizedDescription)", message: "")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }
```